# When and by whom was the Strawsonian Framework extended to forward looking responsibility?

Tags: ethics, free-will, determinism

As I understand it, theories concerning forward-looking responsibility existed before Strawsons 1962 "Freedom and Resentment".
The Categorization of it as backward-looking and the aforementioned views as forward-looking happened later.
I have read papers using the forward-looking responsibility as a self-evident part of the Strawsonian Framework, but couldn't make the same out in their sources.

Now my question is:
When and by whom was it first proposed to include the notion of taking responsibility, as in forward looking responsibility, inside the Strawsonian Framework?
What established the Strawsonian Framework as it is conceived today?
This could of course just be a common concensus, but I expect some sort of classifying paper.

This question is probably easily answered, but so far I have been confused and couldn't find the answer. I have seen papers referencing forward-looking responsibility post Strawson, but nothing I considered definite.

Thanks!